# How long an variable keep its value when app is in background?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

In my android application, MainActivity start. Then user open SecondActivity that have one fragment. After some interactions with fragment, user send app to background by pushing Home button but didn't close application. After 2 hours, user run app again from background and fragment recreate but lifecycle not working!(`onStart()` or `onResume()` not working.)

I save some value to bundle like this:

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        outState.putBoolean("myFlag", true);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

Now, I have two questions:

**First:** How long take an activity recreate when it run again from background?

**Two:** After recreate activity again, why it's variable like booleans didn't initialized again?

Thanks.

Comment: you have to assume that the variable will be gone instantly.  There is no way to determine how long it will be there because you don't know what the memory of the device is.  It's conceivable that they have their background process limit to one.  Always, always keep all important data in a database entry.

Comment: Your application will destroy by the android system to get clear the memory if it is in the background for a long time. You need to save those variables in saved instance state to resume from the same if your app killed by android.

Comment: @JohnLord Thanks. But why  onStart() or onResume() not working when app recreate again?

Comment: @xlu but app didn't destroy and just activity recreate with no calling onResume or onStart.

Comment: I have likely the same issue with my ViewModel found this video helpful and solved my issue. It might also help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sLCn27DceRA&t=808s

Comment: why don't  use [SharedPrefrences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) or dataBase to save your  variable ?

Comment: to be clear, SharedPreferences is a built-in database.

Answer (score -1):

1.) run activity means onCreate recall and all fields will renewed.

2.) As i say when recreate an activity all members of it will renewed if you want store anything, use sharedpreferences or database.

update me in comment if there are more unsolved questions.